# Retrieve value from a drop down in sharepoint list and use those values for infopath drop down

Tags: development, infopath, dropdown

I need to figure out how to get values from the drop down column on SharePoint site and use those values in info path drop down. Can it be down using rules or we need a c# code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a datasource to read data from SharePoint list.

[image]

Then, bind the data to dropdown control.

[image]

[image]